# Making Ubuntu NIC have same static IP address

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have Ubuntu 22.04 in my laptop.  The IP address today changed from 192.168.1.9 to 192.168.1.10.  I tried to specify the old IP address in netplan and applied it and restarted computer still it is taking the new IP address.

```
wlp113s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Here is the /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml  file

```
#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system

network:
    ethernets:
        wlp113s0:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.1.9/32]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4,192.168.1.1]
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
```

I changed addresses section from  192.168.1.1/16  to  192.168.1.9/32 but still IP address shows  192.168.1.10

How to make IP address fixed at  192.168.1.9 ? Where should the settings need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration says it all.  The system is configured to use Network Manager - a separate network management tool - to handle network configuration.  This is defined in `renderer: NetworkManager`.

You need to use Network Manager - which is the GUI network administration tool - to configure your interfaces.  Anything else you enter in Netplan there will be ignored if `renderer: NetworkManager` is present.

Configure the "Ethernet" device in Network Manager with the corresponding IP ranges you want to set, then restart and your IP should change.  Note that if NetworkManager is set to use DHCP then something else on your network has the reservation of `.9` in the address table and the router gave you `.10` intentionally to avoid traffic collisions.